# Can I answer old/dead questions with posts from my blog?

Tags: discussion, spam, old-questions

I've never asked a question on Stack Overflow before.  But I've been to SO quite often after Googling for answers to my questions.  And every now and then, I end up at these great questions which I would love an answer to, but I find the answers unsatisfying (or just nonexistant).

I also write blog posts about my "hard to crack" questions once I've found my answer (usually through hard work; there's no point writing a post about someone else's work unless I add something).  Now I would like to "contribute" this post back to old SO questions which failed me, so anyone else Googling for the same question and ending up on the old thread will see my blog post.

But it feels like spamming, especially if it bumps the question to the top and notifies everyone unnecessarily.  Chances are, the OP doesn't need an answer anymore.  The people I want seeing my answer are those who, like me, happen to get there through Google.

Is it okay for me to answer with blog post links on old/dead questions here on Stack Overflow?

--
P.S. I already read this: [How to refer to your blog when answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering)

I want to know about posting answers on inactive questions.

Comment: What do you mean by a "dead" question? Closed? Inactive? Tumbleweed? With an accepted answer?

Comment: @Richard, He means tumbleweed. (I think)

Comment: The specific question I have in mind is answered but I don't agree with the prevalent answer. But I meant the question more generally than this single question. Is there a "line not to cross"?

Comment: You may want to include the text of your solution in your answer, not just your link, so if the blog falls over the information is still available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the consensus reached on those older questions you link to is just as valid for an old/dead question as it is for a newly posted one. Besides, an old question that is bumped by adding an answer will only transiently float to the top of the [active list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active), and it probably won't appear on the [hot list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=hot) due to its age, so I doubt anyone will be all that bothered by the necroposting.

There's even [a badge for answering old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer), so have at it!

Comment: Alright thanks! This was my main concern as many forums frown upon bumping old threads and I hate receiving email notifications about questions I answered to years ago (on another site, I think you guys work differently).

Comment: @Kevin,  don't worry about bumping old things here.  There isn't the same stigma against it.  And, like @gnovice mentions, it's even encouraged.  [The necromancer badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer)

Answer (score 12):

> Is it ok for me to answer with blog post links on old/dead questions here on StackOverflow?

### For sure!

But, you should follow a few guidelines:

- **Don't** just post a link to the blog.
- Add some context.  Like: "I was also struggling with the same problem and here is how I solved it.
- Post quotes and small code samples from the blog.  Make your answer contain some value besides just a link to the blog.

Comment: And if you're going to link to a blog, try to keep it up.  Nothing sucks worse than reading "And the complete answer may be found at...", only to get a dead link. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific point in time at which a topic is declared dead and no one can revive it. No one's against it, either. Part of the concept of this site is that people in the future will be able to have their questions answered as best as possible; any knowledge that contributes to that is welcomed.