# Posting link to my own site

Tags: discussion, down-votes, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)
>   [How to refer to your blog when answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering)

Sometimes I have posted my own blog post as an answer. While it is in line with the question and accepted as the answer, someone reported and some are down voted. I never used this site as a traffic source to my blog or never tried to spam this. I don't understand what the reason for this is. I don't think I have to rewrite my blog post again on this site.

Comment: Have you read [How to refer to your blog when answering?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering)?

Comment: Did you [merely add the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) or did you summarize what you're explaining in full detail on your site?

Comment: Pure tutorial links are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Adding "you can use Ajax for this" to your answer doesn't really change that.

Comment: Actually, I think this comments you received [on this answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9853409/488657) plus the link I gave you above explain things pretty well.

Comment: To be fair though, your other contributions look great. Just check out some of the discussions here on Meta about how to link to one's blog, heed their advice, and things will be fine. You should at least provide a summary of what the blog post says, and/or show some code samples.

Comment: Understand the reason. but my worry about accepted answers. user accepting answer just because it is useful to him. and we are answering to their question just to improve the knowledge of the community. i'm always putting much more details if i refer to someone else site, because it is not sure about the reliability. But when i refer to my own site i thought no need to put much more details since i already done it in the blog post.

Comment: Got more down votes by posting this question :D. thanks for all the comments and the answer.

Comment: Just update your answer along the lines of what we said here, making it a good answer. People might even revert their downvotes then.

Comment: @Bart: sure, will do it once i got a free time

Comment: Can you guys verify my answer is enough descriptive then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853348/call-backend-method-from-javascript-and-parameter-passing/9853409#9853409

Comment: Looks good to me. +1

Comment: wow, it works. earlier -4 votes now 0 votes :)

Comment: Updated answer as per the comments,finally got deleted my answer :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your article is relevant to the post - by all means give them a link!

If all you are thinking to post is -

> Here try this - http://my-cool-blog.com

Then think again.  Your post could very easily be come a target of some down votes...
There are a few things to take into consideration here -

1. [Proper disclosure of your association to the linked resource](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering).
2. Do not post [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  <sub>There are [systems to prevent this now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130926/increase-minimum-word-count-with-links) but in any case it is important to mention.</sub>

If you want to post a helpful link, make sure that your answer could still stand by itself in the event of link rot.  If that URL happens to go down at some stage - *will your answer still be helpful?*

Always try to include as much information as is necessary and give the link for reference only.  After all - we are in the business of bringing great content here as opposed to linking to great content outside of the site.  I for one do not like to click though things when I am trying to ask or help someone on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +10 for my-cool-blog.com

Comment: Understand the reason. but my worry about accepted answers. user accepting answer just because it is useful to him. and we are answering to their question just to improve the knowledge of the community. i'm always putting much more details if i refer to someone else site, because it is not sure about the reliability. But when i refer to my own site i thought no need to put much more details since i already done it in the blog post.

Comment: The green checkmark is not *all that* important.  It just shows that **the OP chose that answer**.  What you *really* want to be looking at is the community's opinion; That's the answers score. ? Up votes vs. Down votes...