# Can I answer a question with a link of a post of my personal website?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to refer to your blog when answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering)

I am making my own personal website, and probably it will have a blog. Of course, I'm still building it, and it's not available yet, but, let's imagine that I already wrote a post related to a question, and that post has a really good answer for that question, despite that the blog has ads. Can I answer that question with a link of my website?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-do-i-properly-write-an-answer-that-references-my-blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every answer you give links to your blog, or if your answer contains *only* a link to your blog then it'll get deleted.

When I had a blog post already written that addressed the question I've taken the relevant information from the blog and posted it in my answer **so the user isn't required to click-through to get the information**, then I'll put a link to the post (sometimes as a comment on the question) clearly stating that it's my blog for those that think the answer isn't enough.  That said only a couple of answers link to my blog.

Comment: Thanks for pasting the relevant info, since link-rot is a very real thing :)

Comment: Certainly. it's quite frustrating to find a link that promises an answer to your question with a smile and rainbows and unicorns and get a 404.

Answer (score 3):

If your answer consists of only a link to your site (and words to the effect that that's where an answer exists), you will probably get downvoted.

It is *OK* to post a link to your site, but be sure to fully disclose that it is your site. It will be better to post a complete answer (or at least enough for those coming to the question to gain something without having to click through).