# Is it appropriate to move extra info from my answer to a blog post?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, self-promotion, blogging

I have a answer to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667336/1366033) that has generated some good attention, but has grown rather large as I continue to update it and make modifications based on comments.  The post currently has 7,763 characters.   it is larger than 99% of all other answers on stack overflow, according to this [query I made in the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194706/):

[image: screenshot]

This seems too large to quickly convey the most important information,

I have to say that my answers tend to involve a lot of hand holding as I'm often going through that process myself while answering them.  They explain exactly what each and every bit of code does.  This seems like unnecessary noise for someone who is comfortable enough with the framework/language that they could jump right to the answer.

According to [How to refer to your blog when answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20531/209031), it's okay to mention your own blog so long as it's not done excessively, you've disclosed your affiliation, and the answer is good enough on it's own right.

I'd like to trim down the post by just presenting the solution and leaving a lot of the walkthrough to an external resource for people who are interested in being taken through that level of depth.

It seems okay to link to an existing blog post when answering, but is it okay to take content originally created (by me) on this site and remove it by placing it on my personal coding blog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems ideal, but there are dangers.

It stops the answer getting too long, keeps the essential parts of the answer on the site and uses the blog post as more information/reference. Rather than remove content I'd add the link at the stage where the answer is getting "too long" (which will vary from answer to answer).

The only drawback is that, as you have identified, some people might see it as spam. However, if you only do it once or twice then it should be obvious to people that you're not spamming the site. The other thing going in your favour is that you are editing an old answer to add the link rather than just adding the link to all your answers, so the answer is already complete. Spammers don't tend to include an actual answer along with their link - it's extra work they don't like to do.

Comment: I think length is the enemy here. In other forums, I always gain an appreciation for how much SO cares about real estate.  In almost every other Q&A site (*especially the evil EE*), you find yourself scrolling for long periods to get to the *actual* answer. I think we've done well to avoid that.  If I pretend that the order of operations was different, and I already had this blog post detailing every little thing and then I came across this question, I'd most certainly just add the relevant parts and leave the rest for reference.  Since order doesn't matter to new visitors, I think that's best